# How to provide custom converter param at runtime in Dozer component?

Tags: dozer, converters

I have implemented the custom converters with static custom converter param using Dozer field level mapping. But in my case, the custom converter param will change at any time and i need to pass them dynamically.

XML Field Level Dozer Mapping:

```
<field custom-converter-id="decoder" custom-converter-param='{"no":15,"name":"time","size":4,"covert":"test"}'>
        <a>data.message</a>
        <b>test[0].testField</b>
    </field>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Dependency Injection framework you can add parameters to some bean and obtain this bean by programmatic lookup from custom converter

or

you could create a wrapper for source class and pass param to this wrapper (assume source class has type `Source` and target is `Destination`):

```java
public class DataWrapper {
    String param;
    Source wrapped;
    public DataWrapper(Source wrapped, String param) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
        this.param = param;
    }
    public String getParam() {
        return param;
    }
    public Source getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }
}
```

Then you should write a mapping configuration and custom converter for mapping `DataWrapper` class to your `Destination` class:

```xml
    <custom-converters>
        <converter type="your converter">
            <class-a>DataWrapper</class-a>
            <class-b>Destination</class-b>
        </converter>
    </custom-converters>
```

This converter will process `param` and call mapping from `Source` class to `Destination` class (mapping configuration should also exist):

```java
    public Object convert(Object existingDestinationFieldValue, Object sourceFieldValue, Class<?> destinationClass,
        Class<?> sourceClass) {
        DataWrapper wrapper = (DataWrapper) sourceFieldValue;
        String param = wrapper.getParam();
        ...
        return mapper.map(wrapper.getWrapped(), destinationClass);
    }
```

The mapping could be used in the following way:

```java
    DataWrapper wrapper = new DataWrapper(source, "no:15, name:time, size:4, covert:test");
    mapper.map(wrapper, Test.class);
```